# Why is Java's BreakIterator is adding extra commas to my text?

Tags: java, text, nlp, locale

I'm using Java's `BreakIterator` class to break a passage of text into sentences in various languages. It works pretty well, but for some reason it adds commas to the text where they weren't there before.

It looks like it adds:

```
, ,
```

to the text where paragraph breaks are in the original text. It also adds commas before other commas for some reason.

Below is an example of the type of results that I get

> First of all though, I've got to get up,, my train leaves at five
>
> .
>
> ", , And he looked over at the alarm clock, ticking on the chest of, drawers.
>
> "God in Heaven!"

The text should look more like this:

```
First of all though, I've got to get up, my train leaves at five.
And he looked over at the alarm clock, ticking on the chest of drawers.
"God in Heaven!" he thought.
```

This is the original passage:

```
First of all though, I've got to get up,
my train leaves at five."

And he looked over at the alarm clock, ticking on the chest of
drawers.  "God in Heaven!" he thought.
```

I get most of what I need done but I still have to go back after I've broken the text up into sentences and manually edit out all of the extra commas.

As you might have imagined, searching for "java breakiterator extra commas" hasn't gotten me many useful results.

Below is the function that I'm using to do the sentence detection.

```
public ArrayList<String> tokenize(String text, Locale locale)
{
    ArrayList<String> sentences = new ArrayList<String>();
    BreakIterator sentenceIterator = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(locale);
    sentenceIterator.setText(text);
    int boundary = sentenceIterator.first();
    int lastBoundary = 0;
    while (boundary != BreakIterator.DONE)
    {
        boundary = sentenceIterator.next();
        if(boundary != BreakIterator.DONE)
        {
            sentences.add(text.substring(lastBoundary, boundary));
        }
        lastBoundary = boundary;
    }
    return sentences;
}
```

Below is the section of code that I'm using to read in the files to memory and feed them to my sentence splitter:

```
FileHelper fileHelper = new FileHelper();
TextTokenizer textTokenizer = new TextTokenizer();
Constants constants = new Constants();


ArrayList<String> enMetamorph = fileHelper.readFileToMemory(
        constants.books("metamorphosis_en.txt"));

ArrayList<String> enTokenMetamorph = textTokenizer.tokenize(
        enMetamorph.toString(),Locale.US);

fileHelper.writeFile(enTokenMetamorph,constants.tokenized(
        "metamorphosis_en.txt"));
```

The text that I'm using is *The Metamorphosis* by Franz Kafka. You can find a free UTF-8 text version on Project Gutenberg [here](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/5200/pg5200.txt).
The constants object is just used to create filepaths. I use a function called makeFilePath in the books function that will find the books directory no matter what computer the program is run on. That function is below:

```
public static String makeFilePath(String addition)
{
    String filePath = new File("").getAbsolutePath();
    filePath = filePath+addition;
    return filePath;
}
```

Does anybody know why I'm getting all of these extra commas in my text?

Comment: It would make it easier for us to reproduce this issue if you'd provide a short but complete example, complete with sample output and expected output. We might be able to work it out from what you've given us, but it would be much appreciated if you'd do that legwork yourself, as you're in a better position to do so. (And then it's *one* person doing it, rather than each person who's trying to help.)

Comment: Meaning, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JonSkeet I added more detail to the problem description. I included what the original text looks like and what I expect it to look like in the end. I also added a link where you can download the entire original text for yourself and the part of the program that I use to read the file into memory, feed it to my sentence splitter and write my final file.

Comment: @user1803551 I added more detail to the problem description. I included what the original text looks like and what I expect it to look like in the end. I also added a link where you can download the entire original text for yourself and the part of the program that I use to read the file into memory, feed it to my sentence splitter and write my final file.

Comment: You've added more detail, but you haven't provided a short but complete program demonstrating the problem. There should be no need for files etc - just hard code *one* example that fails into a program which *just* demonstrates the issue. We should be able to copy *one* block of code from your post, paste it into a new file, compile, run, and see the incorrect output. Your post should include the expected output, along with a reason why you expect it to be that.

Comment: "Why is Java's BreakIterator is adding extra commas to my text?" It's not, the class just analyzes text, it does not change it. You are doing 2 steps: (1) read a file to memory, (2) write a file from memory. Since the result file is not what you expect, check if the result is correct before outputting it. Check at what stage to the extra commas appear.

Comment: @JonSkeet I did provide a short but working program. The extra details that I provided was all of the code that you needed to be able to run a short program. The only thing that I left out was the main function. I don't know what you mean by there should be no need for files. Can you explain. Breakiterator is used to perform sentence detection. I'm reading the sentences in from a file. I also added what I expect the output to look like. Anyway, I solved the problem thanks to something user1803551 said. Thanks anyway for the feedback.

Comment: @user1803551 Something you said made me think of the problem in a different way. I solved it and I posted my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't with Java's Breakiterator class, the problem was with how Java turns a list of strings into a string.

Below is the line that caused the problem

```
    ArrayList<String> enTokenMetamorph = textTokenizer.tokenize(enMetamorph.toString(),Locale.US);
```

I ended up writing my own toString function that I am now using. It is posted below:

```
public String toString(List<String> strings)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for(String s:strings)
    {
        sb.append(" "+s);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

and the line of code now looks like this:

```
ArrayList<String> enTokenMetamorph = textTokenizer.tokenize(textTokenizer.toString(enMetamorph),Locale.US);
```

This solved the problem. The output now looks like this:

```
First of all though, I've got to get up, my train leaves at five.
And he looked over at the alarm clock, ticking on the chest of drawers.
"God in Heaven!"
he thought.
```

as opposed to this:

```
First of all though, I've got to get up,, my train leaves at five
.
", , And he looked over at the alarm clock, ticking on the chest of, drawers.
"God in Heaven!"
```